# Past perfect vs past simple

Tags: exam-questions

I'd like to ask if the question correct in the first place because I think the answer should have been  **had replaced**  and **evolved** respectively.Because 200,000 years is older than 30,000 years.

> Modern humans, Homo sapiens, ___ in Africa  around 200,000 years ago
>   and by about 30,000 years  ago they ____ all other forms of early
>   humans, such as Neanderthals and Homo erectus.

Answer: evolved / had replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't use the preposition "in" after the verb "replace". This is the first clue that "had replaced" cannot be used in the first blank.

Yes 200,000 is older than 30,000 and you've probably learned to use the past perfect for the action that happened first, but in this case, the action that happened first is "replace". Notice the preposition "by". It shows that the verb "replace" happened before 30,000. Therefore, we must use the past perfect.

If the preposition had been "in" instead of "by", we would use the past simple.

Comment: Thank you.I got it.So the past perfect tense provides a sense of past perfect continuous tense because of "by" . am I right?

Comment: Actually, no. "Had replaced" represents an action that was completed before 30,000 years ago. It is not continuous. In fact, "by" shows that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

"By about 30,000" sets a focus time (in the past), but the "by" makes it explicit that the replacing happened before that focus; therefore the past perfect "had replaced" is appropriate.

Before we get to the "by about 30,000", there is no focus time in the past, so there is no reason to use the past perfect for "evolved". "Had evolved" would be possible, implicitly establishing the focus time after the evolving; but since the focus time is then explicitly set, there is not need, and I don't think it is a likely option.